# Why not add money to killer and not subtract from victim? And the message is not sent

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

No errors, but does nothing if I kill somebody. I used the Essentials Economy for the Money.
I don't know why it doesn't work. This is my Main class
Code:

```java
package me.ghostyy.killmoney;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.PlayerDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import com.earth2me.essentials.api.Economy;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    @EventHandler
    public void deathEvent(PlayerDeathEvent e) {
        Player killer = e.getEntity().getKiller();
        Player victim = e.getEntity();
        if (killer == null)
            return; 
        try {
            double amount = Economy.getMoneyExact(victim.getName()).doubleValue() / 10.0D;
            victim.sendMessage("[§bKillMoney§f]§e You killed §b" + killer.getName() + "§e, you got " + (int)amount + "$!");
            Economy.substract(victim.getName(), BigDecimal.valueOf(amount));
            Economy.add(killer.getName(), BigDecimal.valueOf(amount));
            killer.sendMessage("[§bKillMoney§f]§b " + victim.getName() + "killed you, and lost " + (int)amount + "§e$!");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            return;
        } 
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: is this your full java class?

Comment: https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/using-the-event-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that you are not implementing a Listener in the class **and** not telling the main class that there is a listener class.

Also you should create a new Class as an EventListener, this gives you more overview.
When you create a class named "DeathListener", your class would look like this:

```
package me.ghostyy.killmoney;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.event.EventHandler;
import org.bukkit.event.entity.PlayerDeathEvent;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;
import com.earth2me.essentials.api.Economy;

import org.bukkit.event.Listener;   //importing the Listener

public class DeathListener implements Listener {  //You have to implement the Listener to use it!

@EventHandler
public void deathEvent(PlayerDeathEvent e) {
    Player killer = e.getEntity().getKiller();
    Player victim = e.getEntity();
    if (killer == null)
        return; 
    try {
        double amount = Economy.getMoneyExact(victim.getName()).doubleValue() / 10.0D;
        victim.sendMessage("[§bKillMoney§f]§e You killed §b" + killer.getName() + "§e, you got " + (int)amount + "$!");
        Economy.substract(victim.getName(), BigDecimal.valueOf(amount));
        Economy.add(killer.getName(), BigDecimal.valueOf(amount));
        killer.sendMessage("[§bKillMoney§f]§b " + victim.getName() + "killed you, and lost " + (int)amount + "§e$!");
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        return;
    } 
}

}
```

That's all you have to do in this class. For a new Event, create a new class. 
Last but not least, you have to tell your main class that there is a listener. put the following code into your onEnable() method in your main class:

```
getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new DeathEvent(), this);
```

keep in mind that every class you are creating as an listener has to implement the Listener and has to be added to the PluginManager as shown above.

[EDIT] As Jonas already mentioned, https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/using-the-event-api/ explains it very good!